# Printing months in calendar format in assembly (tasm using dosbox) . My first month keeps getting cut off

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dos, tasm

The first month's first two lines get cut off and I don't know why. It doesn't matter if you switch the order of being printed or delete April; May gets cut off too if you do that. I'm

```
.model tiny
.data

 Apr          db  "         April  2017        ",13,10 
              db  "Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat",13,10 
              db  "                         1 ",13,10 
              db  " 2   3   4   5   6   7   8 ",13,10 
              db  " 9  10  11  12  13  14  15 ",13,10 
              db  "16  17  18  19  20  21  22 ",13,10 
              db  "23  24  25  26  27  28  29 ",13,10  
              db  "30                 ",13,10,0

    May       db  "         May  2017          ",13,10 
              db  "Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat ",13,10 
              db  "      1   2   3   4   5   6 ",13,10 
              db  "  7   8   9  10  11  12  13 ",13,10 
              db  " 14  15  16  17  18  19  20 ",13,10 
              db  " 21  22  23  24  25  26  27 ",13,10 
              db  " 28  29  30  31             "


.code 
    org 100h

    print : 
        mov ah,9
        int 21h
        ret
          end print

   start:   
    lea dx,Apr  
    call print

    lea dx,May  
    call print

    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h

 end start
```

Comment: As specified in the documentation for `int 21h / ah=9`, the string should be terminated by a `'$'`.

Comment: `.model tiny`, `org 100h` (.COM program) and `.data`, `.code ` (.EXE program) don't match. Do you build a .COM program or an .EXE program? Show the command lines with which you build the program.

Comment: Adding '$' doesn't help either. It actually makes it worse because only one line is printing :  16 17 18 19 20.

Comment: I'm using dosbox (tasm). The .data and .code works fine with the exception of a few weird characters after the months print out, if I don't call print and instead write mov ah, 9 and int 21h directly.

Answer (score 3):

You have an early `END` directive.
From the [TASM 5 manual](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/borland/turbo_assembler/Turbo_Assembler_Version_5_Users_Guide.pdf):

> **The END directive**
>   Use the `END` directive to mark the **end of your source file**. The syntax looks like this:
>
> ```
> END [ startaddress ]
> ```
>
> `startaddress` is an optional symbol or expression that specifies the address in your program where you want execution to begin.

The first `end print` terminates the source thereby reducing the program to

```
mov ah, 09h
int 21h
ret
```

As you can see with Turbo Debugger

[image: Turbo debugger showing missing pieces of code]

This causes the observed behavior.

As a note, you can define procedures with a `PROC`/`ENDP` pair but that's not mandatory - it is usually a good practice to write the directives in uppercase to make them stand out when reading the source.

---

Removing the `end print` is not enough to fix your program.
Besides the fact that [INT21h/AH=9](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm) requires the string to be terminated with a `$` (both of them), when you come to link the object file TLINK will complain.

> Fatal: Cannot generate COM file: Data below initial CS:IP defined

This is to be expected as the COM file format is pure, raw code with no metadata at all.
The entry-point is defined to be the offset 100h and cannot be forced to a different address with the full version of the `END` directive - the one that takes `[startaddress]`.

You have to move the `print` procedure down.

```
.model tiny
.data

 Apr          db  "         April  2017        ",13,10 
              db  "Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat",13,10 
              db  "                         1 ",13,10 
              db  " 2   3   4   5   6   7   8 ",13,10 
              db  " 9  10  11  12  13  14  15 ",13,10 
              db  "16  17  18  19  20  21  22 ",13,10 
              db  "23  24  25  26  27  28  29 ",13,10  
              db  "30                 ",13,10,24h

    May       db  "         May  2017          ",13,10 
              db  "Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat ",13,10 
              db  "      1   2   3   4   5   6 ",13,10 
              db  "  7   8   9  10  11  12  13 ",13,10 
              db  " 14  15  16  17  18  19  20 ",13,10 
              db  " 21  22  23  24  25  26  27 ",13,10 
              db  " 28  29  30  31             ", 24h


.code 

org 100h




   start:   

    lea dx,Apr  
    call print

    lea dx,May  
    call print

    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h

print : 
        mov ah,9
        int 21h
        ret
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Also, thank you for going into detail about my errors. I'm new to assembly language and that was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I did some changes to your code, now it does what it should:

1) .model tiny has data and code in the same segment, and you need a jump over the data part to your starting address. since you already have 2 segements, changing to `.model small` and removing the .org fixed this (this includes the need of initializing data segment DS)

2) DOS Int 21/9 prints everthing it finds, up to a "$". so only one print was needed

3) DOS int 21/4c returns AL as error code, since there was no error, better return a 0

```
.model small
.data

    Cal       db  "         April  2017        ",13,10 
              db  "Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat",13,10 
              db  "                         1 ",13,10 
              db  " 2   3   4   5   6   7   8 ",13,10 
              db  " 9  10  11  12  13  14  15 ",13,10 
              db  "16  17  18  19  20  21  22 ",13,10 
              db  "23  24  25  26  27  28  29 ",13,10  
              db  "30                 ",13,10,0

    May       db  "         May  2017          ",13,10 
              db  "Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat ",13,10 
              db  "      1   2   3   4   5   6 ",13,10 
              db  "  7   8   9  10  11  12  13 ",13,10 
              db  " 14  15  16  17  18  19  20 ",13,10 
              db  " 21  22  23  24  25  26  27 ",13,10 
              db  " 28  29  30  31             "

    EndStr    db "$"   ;  tell DOS to stop printing here


.code 

start:
    mov ax,@data       ; initialize data segment
    mov ds,ax

    mov dx,offset Cal  ; print Calender
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4c00h      ; return to DOS
    int 21h

end start
```